# Custom 404 handler Laravel 5.2 with blade

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've created a custom view in the views/errors directory called 404.blade.php per documented in laravel docs [Laravel custom http docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#http-exceptions) , but when I include a master template it throws a ErrorException. If I remove the @extends('master') from the error view and just use custom html it works find. Is there a way to extend or include master template in my error views?

Here's my stack trace.

```
ErrorException in 6d81dce21d9f786092d4f08b2291187254557680.php line 41:
Trying to get property of non-object (View C:\xampp\htdocs\auto_responder\resources\views\layouts\site_master.blade.php)  (View:   C:\xampp\htdocs\auto_responder\resources\views\layouts\site_master.blade.php)
 in 6d81dce21d9f786092d4f08b2291187254557680.php line 41
 at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
 at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\auto_responder\storage\framework\views/a853a92ee6 c1570e0a223b96c01698d12a46f009.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' =>  object(Application), 'exception' => object(NotFoundHttpException))) in  CompilerEngine.php line 59
  at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\auto_responder\resources\views/errors/404.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'exception' => object(NotFoundHttpException))) in View.php line 149
  at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
  at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
  at View->render() in Response.php line 53
  at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
  at Response->__construct(object(View), '404', array()) in ResponseFactory.php line 57
  at ResponseFactory->make(object(View), '404', array()) in ResponseFactory.php line 71
   at ResponseFactory->view('errors.404', array('exception' => object(NotFoundHttpException)), '404', array()) in Handler.php line 156
  at Handler->renderHttpException(object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Handler.php line 113
  at Handler->render(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Handler.php line 48
  at Handler->render(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Pipeline.php line 80
  at Pipeline->handleException(object(Request), object(NotFoundHttpException)) in Pipeline.php line 54
  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
  at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
  at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
  at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
  at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
  at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
  at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
  at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

So I guess my question is, is this suppose to be like this, or am I doing something wrong. All my other views work perfectly using the exact same syntax to extend.

Comment: Could you provide the master template here. Most probably your master view must be expecting any variable from invoking controller.